# How can I replace a pergola ledger that's right under-roof?

Tags: deck, siding, decking, pergola, ledger

I was thinking about replacing my older deck/pergola. I’m planning to do a similar build of the existing deck and feel somewhat confident with the framing and posts. However, I could use some guidance with the pergola ledger.

**Context:**
I’m a new homeowner and a complete novice so bear with me –  I’m a little uncertain about the pergola ledger for the house. The house is a brick ranch and a 2x6 ledger is attached to some white siding/trim? It’s attached with 3 lag bolts (two on the ends and one in the middle). There’s a flashing that hangs off the soffit.

[image]

[image]

Now, I ran a stud finder over the area and the bolts do appear to be in “studs”. It seems like there’s some wood siding potentially under the white siding, but I’m not certain. I was ultimately hoping to swap in a fresh 2x8 ledger board attached with LedgerLOKs.

**Questions:**

How would you approach this situation to feel more confident about swapping in a 2x8 that’s up to code?

Should the existing flashing be sufficient for this use case?

Comment: If you're taking it down anyway, why not wait and see? It's either lagged to the brick or something behind it. Well done with your first post, by the way.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, @isherwood! Yeah, that's honestly probably the best plan --see what's actually behind the ledger before making any final decisions. Do you think I'd be able to see that area if I crawled through my attic?

Comment: Nope. What you need to see is outside.